# Vim different color scheme when printing

Tags: vim

Is there a way in _vimrc to set a different colorscheme to be used when printing files?

I like a dark background light text scheme on screen, but obviously that doesn't translate well to paper.

Edit: I can change the scheme manually before printing, then change it back after and it works fine. Just curious if there's a way to tell Vim to always use a specific scheme while printing.

This is what `:hardcopy` outputs:
[image]

Comment: I can't get the `vimrc` tag to work..

Comment: How about something like `:command Hardcopy let colors_save = g:colors_name <Bar> colorscheme default <Bar> hardcopy <Bar> execute 'colorscheme' colors_save`?  Maybe throw in the `'bg'` option.

Comment: @Dan the vimrc tag is a synonym for vim.

Comment: @benjifisher Wow! Please post that as an answer so I can accept it. Creative solution that does exactly what I want.

Comment: @Downvoter: Mind explaining why you down voted a 3-year-old question that's already been answered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like

```
:command Hardcopy let colors_save = g:colors_name <Bar> colorscheme default <Bar> hardcopy <Bar> execute 'colorscheme' colors_save
```

Maybe throw in the `'bg'` option.  If you care about local variables, make it a function:

```
command Hardcopy call Hardcopy()
function! Hardcopy()
  let colors_save = g:colors_name
  colorscheme default
  hardcopy
  execute 'colorscheme' colors_save
endfun
```

Answer (score 3):

The Vim plugin ["Printer Dialog"](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=512) allows to configure printing parameters, one of them is the colorscheme to be used for printing.

After installing and configuring "Printer Dialog" press `\pd` in the Vim window you want to print. The following "dialog" will open:

[image]

Beneath other things the syntax-highlighting for printing can be selected. See `:help printer-dialog` for further details. 
The variable `g:prd_syntaxList` defines the syntax-highlightings that can be selected. Default is

```
g:prd_syntaxList = "no,current,default,print_bw,zellner"
```

See `:help prd_syntaxList` for details on how to setup this feature.

Comment: Neat plugin, though I prefer ben's simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

`:hardcopy` will always print with a white background. From `:help hardcopy`:

```
The current highlighting colors are used in the printout, with the following
considerations:
1) The normal background is always rendered as white (i.e. blank paper).
2) White text or the default foreground is rendered as black, so that it shows
   up!
3) If 'background' is "dark", then the colours are darkened to compensate for
   the fact that otherwise they would be too bright to show up clearly on
   white paper.
```

However, I'm not sure how exactly "[...] the colours are darkened to compensate [...]" works, so you may still want to go with @benjifisher's solution.

Alternatively, you could use `:TOhtml` to get an identical representation (definitely with a different colorscheme in this case), and then print that out in some other way. See `:help TOhtml` for relevant options, e.g. `g:html_number_lines`.

Comment: `:hardcopy` produces undesirable results. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Using :TOhtml works quite well. It creates a html file with the same colour scheme being used.

I like the [onehalf](https://github.com/sonph/onehalf/tree/master/vim) (link to github  download instructions for vim) colour schemes because it it has a simple light and dark scheme. The syntax highlighting is the same between both schemes, besides white and black text which is switched.

So you can have a dark scheme on your computer, and then still print your code out and retain the general syntax highlighting which I find really useful.

this is what I do:

1. open the code I want to print
2. change to light scheme if not already in it by `:colorscheme :onehalflight`
3. run `:TOhmtl` which also opens the html file in vim
4. go to new html file, and save it to desired location
   example, to save as text.html to downloads: `:w ~/Downloads/text.html`
5. open saved html file with your favourite browser, and print or do whatever you
   want, this is nice because it allows you to see how many pages you are going to
   print before you break your printer!